# Enable auto (self)-closing tags for JSX in MDX file

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby, prettier, mdxjs

I am moving a website to Gatsby. For article posts, the original source was written as HTML files. I want to take advantage of using MDX for those content. However, copy-paste tons of articles from HTML to MDX produce much pain. Particularly, MDX parser usually complains about `Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for ...`
I wonder if prettier or any formatter can help with auto adding self-closing tags for MDX files.

Example:

```
<img
  class="wp-image-1221 size-full"
  src="/assets/images/articles-news/Yasmin_pic_4.png"
  alt=""
  width="504"
  height="377"
>
```

Expected formatted output

```
<img
  class="wp-image-1221 size-full"
  src="/assets/images/articles-news/Yasmin_pic_4.png"
  alt=""
  width="504"
  height="377"
/>

// or

<img
  class="wp-image-1221 size-full"
  src="/assets/images/articles-news/Yasmin_pic_4.png"
  alt=""
  width="504"
  height="377"
></img>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Prettier MDX parser fails at parsing tags that are not self-closing, like the `img` in your example ([playground](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAeAlgWwOYB0oAEBYANgIYDOFAvLiAO4AOAtFmdnMwIwBMPXBCugBenAGYBXEiTr4iFAE5haIAPSUKcGBVVsOOsgpjpScCsyhx6OgJqVM6KAH1GJpwBYAdIyh4QcgjISGBVZQgJ6dAATGAALFQBWAAZ3MKJYuHRsWJC6AGYAdgKwgD4QABoQCEZjaApkUEMFCHoABUMEepQg+jIAT3rKgCMFMjAAay0AZUYxx2xkGAUJOEqczBIAdVj0eApZsDgpzt30ADddvuRwKgqQR00jVtHsTDJkMSDNSoArCgAPABCowm0zImDgABlHHAPl9ViA-v8pvMSHAAIoSCDwOEkb4gWYKR7XTBRf53RgKRwwTbROLIAAcSUqlIgmk2o0Y10pZjgCjOsMqAEcsfBntUuiBKBY4HAonK7go4CL0Ernuw3rj8ZoHItlgihL40ZjsbCkJ88QiYGQhrSYrFkDxKksyOgSPMAMIQTCalBmBJ3CSaAAqNq6FvxZxWAEkoPLYFMwFSagBBONTGB9NFauAAX1zQA)). However, if you use the HTML parser, Prettier will add the closing `/` ([playground](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAeAlgWwOYB0oAEBYANgIYDOFAvLiAO4AOAtFmdnMwIwBMPXBCugBenAGYBXEiTr4iFAE5haIAPSUKcGBVVsOOsgpjpScCsyhx6OgJqVM6KAH1GJpwBYAdIyh4QcgjISGBVZQgJ6dAATGAALFQBWAAZ3MKJYuHRsWJC6AGYAdgKwgD4QABoQCEZjaApkUEMFCHoABUMEepQg+jIAT3rKgCMFMjAAay0AZUYxx2xkGAUJOEqczBIAdVj0eApZsDgpzt30ADddvuRwKgqQR00jVtHsTDJkMSDNSoArCgAPABCowm0zImDgABlHHAPl9ViA-v8pvMSHAAIoSCDwOEkb4gWYKR7XdYkO6MBSOGCbaJxZAADiSlQpEE0m1GjGuFLMcAUZ1hlQAjlj4M9ql0QJQLHA4FFZXcFHBhehFc92G9cfjNA5FssEUJfGjMdjYUhPniETAyEMaTFYsgeJUlmR0CR5gBhCCYDUoMwJO4STQAFWtXXN+LOKwAklA5bApmBKTUAIKxqYwPpozVwAC+OaAA)).

Use the [`--parser` option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#parser) to format using the HTML parser (note that you need to do it **before** adding your MDX frontmatter, otherwise the HTML parser won't be able to parse the files either):

```sh
prettier --parser html --write ./my-html-files-from-wordpress
```

Once the elements are all (self-)closing, you can switch back to using Prettier's inferred parser (MDX for .mdx files):

```sh
prettier --write ./my-formatted-mdx-files
```